# Найти в двух списках числа, сумма которых равна заданному числу

Tags: python, python-3.x

заданное число (например 11), и есть списки чисел **например** `[1, 2, 3, 5]` и
`[6, 1, 3]` необходимо найти числа сумма которых равна заданному числу. пробовал реализовать на Python , но безуспешно

```
# ввод
r30, r10, r20 = (int(num) for num in input().split())
# все возможные числа для перемножения

numbers = []
r30_1 = r30
while r30_1 >= 0:
    numbers.append(r30_1)
    r30_1 -= 1

numbers.reverse()

numbers = numbers[:numbers.index(r30) + 1]

print(numbers)

res_list1 = [r10 * x for x in numbers if isinstance(x, int)]
res_list2 = [r20 * y for y in numbers if isinstance(y, int)]


# оставить только числа до конечных
res_list1 = res_list1[:res_list1.index(r30) + 1]
res_list2 = res_list2[:res_list2.index(r30) + 1]

result = []
result1 = []

res_list_result = [a + b for a, b in zip(res_list1, res_list2)]
for i in res_list_result:
    if i == r30:
        result.append(i)

print(res_list1)
print(res_list2)
print(result)
```

это попытка решения 1 задачи с acm.timus ,но проблема в том что в конце выходит [] ,из за того что это обычная сумма по 2 числа из разных списков ,
подскажите как организовать алгоритм перебора слагаемых

> **формат вывода**

```
0 12

5 9

10 6

15 3

20 0
```

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки с помощью кнопки править

Comment: Т.е. одно число из одного списка, другое из второго? Нужны только пары сумма которых равна заданному числу? И какой формат вывода?

Comment: да всё верно , я предоставил формат вывода поправив вопрос

Comment: @strawdog [Устанавливайте её вместе с меткой python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
condition = int(input())
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 5]
list_b = [6, 1, 3]
for a in list_a:
  for b in list_b:
    if (a + b) == condition:
       print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product # Декартово произведение iterable объектов
condition_number = int(input()) # Число для которого сумма пары дает его.
list_a, list_b = [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 1, 3] # Списки которые перебираем
answer = [f'{x} {y}' for x,y in product(list_a, list_b) if x + y == condition_number]
# Перебираем все пары из list_a, list_b, оставляем только те, 
# которые дают в сумме наперед заданному числу, оставляем их в списке в виде строки 'x y'
# пользуясь f-строками.
print(*answer, sep='\n') 
# Печатаем все элементы, по умолчанию через пробел, 
# но мы задали sep='\n', заменив пробел переводом строки
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант не является самым оптимальным. Что если во втором списке миллион чисел? Все перебирать? Лучше использовать сет и такой вариант:

```
s = int(input())
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 5]
list_b = [6, 1, 3]
list_b = set(list_b)
for a in list_a:
    if s-a in list_b: 
        print(a, s-a)
        break # опционально. Если достаточно найти только одну пару
```